Python Curses printing getkey() errors
The problem here is i can't get the exact letter i type in showing up in the console
I'm launching the code with CMD there is no problem launching the code
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.keypad(True) #Activates special characters

    while True:
        ch = stdscr.getkey()
        if ch == curses.KEY_ENTER:
            break
        stdscr.addstr(0, 0, ch)
        stdscr.refresh()

curses.wrapper(main)
    

Eventually, when I press "i" or "ü" or "ı" in the console, I'm getting something weird.
when i press "i" this shows up
and also when i press "ı" i get
and when i press "ü" i get ValueError: embedded null character
I'm not sure to how to fix it. I have nearly searched entire stackoverflow
Curses version is windows-curses-2.3.3.
Python version is 3.12.
Code editor is PyCharm Community.
I tried solving it with ord() and chr() and str(),
but none of them seemed to be working.
I tried getch(), but it also didn't work.
ch=chr(stdscr.getch()).encode("utf-8")
I also tried encoding but it also didn't work.
I searched the document a bit, and I couldn't see anything useful.

You'll have to set the locale (and since the underlying curses is PDCurses, that may/may not work).

@Tarık Can KARADENİZ –
I can't reproduce the described behavior with the same Curses version, Python 3.8.1 and 3.10.7 - when I press 'ü', I get 'ü'; pressing Enter I get the line feed character, so I have to use Ctrl-C to interrupt the script.
